# Forcing a timeout for FileManager().copyItem(_:_)

Tags: objective-c, swift, macos, timeout, nsfilemanager

I am using

```
try FileManager.default.copyItem(at: inFile, to: outFile)
```

The problem is it's a large file on a questionable network and processing done by something unattended.  I would like to be able to tell FileManager to only take a minute to do the copy, otherwise nope out.

I can't seem to find it in the documentation and my Bing-fu is weak today.

Comment: Maybe with those requirements you should write your own file copy that does it in parts and then you can have more control and e.g. exit early.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up extending FileManager with a dispatchWorkItem and custom error struct.

```
public extension FileManager {
    struct TimeoutError:Error{
        let source:URL
        let destination:URL
        let timeOut:Double
    }

    func timedOutCopy(at source:URL, to destionation:URL, timeOut:Double = 15.0) throws {
        var cpError:Error?
        let d = DispatchWorkItem(block: {
            do {
                try self.copyItem(at: source, to: destionation)
            } catch {
                cpError = error
            }
        })
        DispatchQueue.global().async(execute: d)
        if d.wait(wallTimeout: DispatchWallTime.now() + timeOut) != .success {
            d.cancel()
            throw TimeoutError(source: source, destination: destionation, timeOut: timeOut)
        } else {
            if let cpError = cpError {throw cpError}
        }
    }
}
```